# Swiftでのfor文の書き換えについて

Tags: swift

Swiftではmap,filterなどの便利な機能があるのであまりfor文を使わない方がいいと聞いたのですが、以下のような場合も書き換え可能な方法がありますでしょうか。

```
var test = ["りんご","ごりら","らっぱ","ぱらしゅーと","とんねる"]
for i in 0..<test.count{
    if test[i] == "ごりら"{
        test[i] = "ごじら"
    }
}
```

要素をすべて確認して、一致する場合、一致した要素そのものに変更を加えたいのです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` の中で条件分岐をすれば良いです。

```
test.map { (s: String) -> String in
    if (s == "ごりら") {
        return "ごじら"
    } else {
        return s
    }
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5Nt2ucI0OTZBQYhI)

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました！

Comment: @Avel もしよろしければ[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)して頂けると僕が嬉しいです :)

Comment: すみません、承認が遅れ申し訳ありません。重ね重ねありがとうございました！

Answer (score 5):

forとmapは役割が異なるので、単純に置き換えられるわけではありません。
例に挙げられたプログラムの場合、forループでtest配列そのものを書き換えていますが、mapの場合はtest配列はそのままで、新しい配列がmapの戻り値として返ってきます。
参考までに。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。大量のデータの一部分だけ書き換えたい場合は、多少不恰好になってもforを使った方がメモリ的には良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

内部引数名の省略表記（$0）や三項演算子（?）を使ってこんな風にも記述できます。

```
var test = ["りんご","ごりら","らっぱ","ぱらしゅーと","とんねる"]
test = test.map {
    $0 == "ごりら" ? "ごじら" : $0
}
```

今回は配列に変更を加える場合なので、変更後の配列を返すmapを利用しましたが、
変更を加えない場合はmapの代わりにforEachを利用すると良いかと思います。

```
var test = ["りんご","ごりら","らっぱ","ぱらしゅーと","とんねる"]
test.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上例はかなり記述を簡略化できるのですね。大変参考になりました。